# Access branch.io referral reward information on node server

Tags: node.js, react-native, branch.io, referrals

I want to reward some in-app rewards to users for referring a friend and thinking of using branch.io.

I have understood that you can reward users a branch reward based on rule set on branch.io dashboard. I have also understood that the client (user) can call `branch.redeemRewards()` to redeem the branch rewards.

I am trying to find a way to award some **in-app rewards** to the users though, and for doing so I need to inform my node server about these.

1. Is there a branch node sdk?
2. How can the server check and redeem the branch reward of each user and award them an in-app reward?
3. How should this flow work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. Is there a branch node sdk?*

Branch doesn't have a node SDK, but they do have HTTP APIs to perform all the operations facilitated in native SDK: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/.

*3. How can the server check and redeem the branch reward of each user and award them an in-app reward?*

You can check and redeem the Branch rewards using the HTTP API.

For example :

To check the credits:

```
curl -XGET 'https://api.branch.io/v1/credits?branch_key=key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt&identity=steve'
```

To redeem credits

```
  curl -XPOST https://api.branch.io/v1/redeem \
  -d '{
  "branch_key": "key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt",
  "branch_secret": "secret_live_RrrsLqpzVcoVWf5t4ncQVpzlg2pRpGH9",
  "identity": "steve",
  "amount": "5",
  "bucket": "default"
}'
```

The best practice in referral programs is to check the balance and redeem credits on client side (on mobile app).

*2. How should this flow work?*

There are two actors in the referral program: Referrer user and referred user. Before going through implementation, do go through online docs to setup referral rules on Dashboard: https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/referrals/#give-reward

For referrer User within the app (using mobile SDK):

1. Set the user identity after initSession for example in iOS:

   [[Branch getInstance] setIdentity:@"your_user_id"];
   https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#track-users
2. Share a link to the friend (referred user). 
   https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#share-deep-link

When the referred User deep links back inside the app after installation:

1. Set the user identity
2. Trigger the custom event you have setup in reward rules on the Dashboard
   https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#track-events
3. Check the balance of the credits and redeem the credits:
   https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#handle-referrals

Comment: Thank you @ParthKalavadia for your answer, but why is it the best practice to check the balance and redeem credits on client side? From a security point of view, how can you guarantee that branch.io rewards correctly correspond to in-app reward or real-money? Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I think you need to check Branch webhook. It allows to you to send callbacks to your server after specific event (install...)